# Mapping redo in insert mode VIM

Tags: vimrc, keymap

How to remap a redo shortcut (Ctrl-R in normal) to Ctrl-Shift-Z in insert mode?

It would be helpful since I mapped undo to Ctrl-Z like this:

```
nnoremap <c-z> :u<CR>
vnoremap <c-z> :u<CR> 
inoremap <c-z> <c-o>:u<CR>
vnoremap <c-z> <c-o>:u<CR>
```

So I want: undo - `Ctrl-Z`, redo - `Ctrl-Shift-Z` as in another text editors.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555779/how-do-i-do-redo-i-e-undo-undo-in-vim), but it is just for normal mode change Ctrl-R to U. Not quite what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
inoremap <c-s-z> <c-o><c-r>
```